# select tag color doesnt show in firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I have a webpage with a simple select dropdown, in which each of the option elements has a different colour.  When expanded the colours show up fine in Firefox (8.0), however as soon as you click an option and the list closes the colour goes back to black.

As I am writing a summary webpage the colours are important.

This issue doesnt seem to appear in IE

```
<select name='STATUS' style='width:100px'>
  <option value='NS' style='color:blue'>Not Started</option>
  <option value='Started' style='color:Green'>Started</option>
  <option value='Finished' style='color:red'>Finished</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `color` declaration only affects the your `option` elements, not the chosen option. The style of the chosen option is determined by the style of your `select` element. You have to change the color of the `select` element with JavaScript in order to achieve your desired behavior:

```
<select class="colorchange" name='STATUS' style='width:100px;'>
  <option value='NS' style='color:blue'>Not Started</option>
  <option value='Started' style='color:Green'>Started</option>
  <option value='Finished' style='color:red'>Finished</option>
</select>
```

```js
function selectColorChanger(){
    this.style.color = this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.color;
}

// this will affect all selects which have the "colorchange" class applied
var selects = document.getElementsByClassName("colorchange");
var i;

for(i = 0; i < selects.length; ++i){
    selects[i].onchange = selectColorChanger;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vTSrH/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the code works, however I need a solution which has a colour on the select when the page loads so that people can see the status as soon as they load the page.
I will be adding in the code to auto select the correct option when the page loads later

Comment: The solution I have come up with is using PHP to add a style="color:$COLOR" element to the select tag itself.  
As the current Status is held in a DB when rendering the page, I check what status is currently active and set the $COLOR var accordingly.

Thanks for the help.  Shame Firefox doesn't render it automatically like IE chrome etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have come up with is using PHP to add a style="color:$COLOR" element to the select tag itself.
As the current Status is held in a DB when rendering the page, I check what status is currently active and set the $COLOR var accordingly.

Thanks for the help.  Shame Firefox doesn't render it automatically like IE chrome etc.